# How to Build Android project that uses Xamarin.Forms.Maps?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created a new Xamarin Forms solution with .Net Standard 2.0
It builds OK.

Then I add a NuGet Xamarin.Forms.Maps:

and appear this Build error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       An error occurred trying to install required android components on Project 'eCidadaoMobile.Android'.
Project 'eCidadaoMobile.Android' requires the following components installed on your machine: 
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base
JavaLibraryReference: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r24.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.4.0/play-services-base-8.4.0.aar-8.4.0
AndroidResources: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r24.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.4.0/play-services-base-8.4.0.aar-8.4.0
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement
JavaLibraryReference: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r24.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/8.4.0/play-services-basement-8.4.0.aar-8.4.0
AndroidResources: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r24.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/8.4.0/play-services-basement-8.4.0.aar-8.4.0
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps
JavaLibraryReference: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r24.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.4.0/play-services-maps-8.4.0.aar-8.4.0
AndroidResources: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r24.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.4.0/play-services-maps-8.4.0.aar-8.4.0


Please double-click here to install it.

Intallation Errors: XA5207 Please install package: 'GPS Base' available in SDK installer. Java library file 'C:\Users\tonyv\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar' doesn't exist.
XA5207 Please install package: 'GPS Basement' available in SDK installer. Java library file 'C:\Users\tonyv\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement\8.4.0\content\classes.jar' doesn't exist.
XA5207 Please install package: 'GPS Maps' available in SDK installer. Java library file 'C:\Users\tonyv\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps\8.4.0\content\classes.jar' doesn't exist.         0
```

If I double-click the error message, nothing happens.

**How and where to install these required files?**

Comment: Have you tried to delete Xamarin.GooglePlayServices folders in the AppData/Local/Xamarin path? It should redownload them on the next startup

Comment: Hey, it worked. Please post this comment as answer so I can mark as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the path `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin`, delete the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices` folders, in order to redownload them during the next startup.